# Common Lisp: How to import symbols of other packages inside a lexical scope only?

Tags: import, common-lisp, temporal

I want to use some functions inside another package with a long name (e.g., "sb-bsd-sockets"), and I have to write this:

```
(defun myfun (...)
   (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-bind ...)
   (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-listen ...)
   ...)
```

Is there a way to import some of those symbols only available inside `myfun` (without any performance loss)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is the first thing that popped into my head (a simple tree walk and replace of symbol names).

It should be noted that the question was about **importing** symbols and the following does not do that. It simply adds the ugly package-name:: part for you.

```
(defmacro with-symbols-from ((package-name &rest symbols) &body body)
  (let ((f-symbols (loop :for s :in symbols :collect 
                      (intern (symbol-name s) package-name))))
    `(progn
       ,@(loop :for symbol :in symbols :for f-symbol :in f-symbols 
            :with body = body
            :do (setf body (subst f-symbol symbol body :test #'eq))
            :finally (return body)))))
```

Usage example:

```
CL-USER> (with-symbols-from (:cffi foreign-alloc mem-aref)
           (let ((a (foreign-alloc :int)))
             (setf (mem-aref a :int) 1)
             (mem-aref a :int)))
1
```

The above expanded to:

```
(PROGN
 (LET ((A (CFFI:FOREIGN-ALLOC :INT)))
   (SETF (CFFI:MEM-AREF A :INT) 1)
   (CFFI:MEM-AREF A :INT)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside a function, no: the [`defun`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm) form is [`read`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) in the current [`*package*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pkg.htm), and the symbols therein are resolved *before* anything else (inside it) is processed.

However, you can do something like this (untested and *not* recommended):

```
(defpackage #:tmp (:use cl sb-bsd-sockets))
(in-package #:tmp)

(defun old-pack::myfun ...)

(in-package old-pack) ; the package which was current before `tmp` was created
(delete-package #:tmp)
```

Generally speaking, it is not a good idea.

It would be much cleaner to move the socket code into a separate file with a separate package and then use that package in the other files.

Comment: Thanks. and one more question: is there a way to use a temporary nickname for a package?

Comment: You can use `defpackage` to change the list of nicknames.

Answer (score 2):

The question that immediately comes to mind is "why would you want to do that?"

I would, normally, simply import the the package into the (project-specific) package that needed it and/or structure my project package tree such that if I absolutely cannot have package B imported into package A, have a package A-sub that imports it, exports a few functions, then call A-sub:function from other code within package A.

As a general rule, if you are trying to do something that seems awkward in Common Lisp, it's probably time to take a short step back and consider if what you're trying to do is the best way of accomplishing what you want (in this case, the question could be "does it matter if the symbol `socket-bind` is imported from sb-bsd-sockets?" and if the answer isn't a resounding YES, then simply import socket-bind into your package).

Comment: hmm, I want to use some functions of `sb-bsd-sockets` in one or two of my functions, and I don't want to expose `socket-xxx` things to other parts of my code to prevent name conflicts. I don't want A-sub solution because there are only one or two functions that need `socket-xxx`. Now my solution is `(defpackage #:tmp (:use #:sb-bsd-sockets #:others))` and then use `tmp::socket-xxx` instead, and finally `(delete-package #:tmp)`. This one is still not very nice, too.

Comment: @SaltyEgg If you end up having name conflicts, you can always shadow those symbols on import. You don't have to contort yourself, until there's explicit need for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is [import](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_import.htm) function as well.

```lisp
(import 'sb-bsd-sockets:socket-bind)
(import 'sb-bsd-sockets:socket-listen)
(socket-listen) ;; error, but found
```